# Como usar uma var counter no Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

É possível criar uma variável contadora no thymeleaf? Preciso de uma variável incremental para passar como ID de tags no HTML.
Tenho os seguintes laços de repetição, onde cada laço ira ser iterado x vezes diferentes, então não consigo usar o index de nenhum dos laços para definir o id das tags que devem ser sequenciais (valor0, valor1, valor2...).

```
<div class="col m12">
   <div th:each="e, index : ${produto.etapasTrabalho}">
      <div th:each="t : ${e.tarefas}">
         <div th:each="i : ${t.itensTarefa}">
            <div id="campo" class="campo input-field col m8" th:if="${i.tipo.toString() == 'Data'}">
               <input type="text" id="id" th:value="${i.id}" th:hidden="hidden" />
               <label th:text="${i.nome}"></label>
               <input type="text" th:value="${i.valor}" class="datepicker" th:id="'valor'+${index}" />
            </div>
            <div id="campo" class="campo input-field col m8" th:if="${i.tipo.toString() == 'Texto'}">
               <input type="text" id="id" th:value="${i.id}" th:hidden="hidden" />
               <input type="text" th:id="'valor'+${index}" th:value="${i.valor}" />
               <label th:text="${i.nome}"></label>
            </div>
            <div id="campo" class="campo input-field col m8" th:if="${i.tipo.toString() == 'Texto Longo'}">
               <input type="text" id="id" th:value="${i.id}" th:hidden="hidden" />
               <textarea class="materialize-textarea" th:value="${i.valor}" th:id="'valor'+${index}"></textarea>
               <label th:text="${i.nome}"></label>
            </div>
            <div id="campo" class="campo input-field col m8" th:if="${i.tipo.toString() == 'Dinheiro $'}">
               <input type="text" id="id" th:value="${i.id}" th:hidden="hidden" />
               <input class="money" type="text" th:value="${i.valor}" th:id="'valor'+${index}" />
               <label th:text="${i.nome}"></label>
            </div>
            <div id="campo" class="campo" th:if="${i.tipo.toString() == 'Check'}">
               <input type="text" id="id" th:value="${i.id}" th:hidden="hidden" />
               <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="check" th:id="'valor'+${index}" />
               <label for="check" th:text="${i.nome}"></label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Caso não seja possível, eu posso usar uma variável do javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução através do javascript, simplesmente busco todos os campos contenham certa classe e defino o atributo id do elemento com o index do each.

```
$('.campo').each(function(i) {
       $(this).attr('id', 'valor' + i);
    });
```